# Por que esse simples código em Haskell não compila?

Tags: haskell

Estou estudando Haskell, e não entendo por que esse código não compila:

```
foo :: Int -> Double -> Double
foo a b = a+b
```

A mensagem de erro é:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Int'
In the first argument of `(+)', namely `a'
In the expression: a + b
In an equation for `foo': foo a b = a + b
```

Eu sei que o operador '+' é uma função com os parâmetros

```
(+) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

mas os tipos Int e Double são instâncias de Num.

Então, Por que o compilador não aceita esse código??

Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Não existem instâncias em linguagens funcionais da mesma maneira que em linguagens procedurais; Num é uma classe no sentido de que existem tipos que pertençam a ela, mas não quer dizer que sejam equivalentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método de (+) trabalha com qualquer tipo, mas ele necessita que os dois elementos sejam do mesmo tipo. Quando ele identifica que o primeiro elemento é um Int, ele infere que o outro também será. Para sua adição funcionar, é necessário converter os elementos para o mesmo tipo.

Isso ocorre devido a [Monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction), quando você não especifica o tipo, ele irá inferir os tipos usando regras de tipificação padrão, o exemplo é exatamente a funcão de soma (+). O `(+) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a` , ficará `Int -> Int -> Int`

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8262122/9916784

Comment: Alterado como pedido.

Comment: Pode deixar o link tb como completo, fica bem jóia com o principal aqui e o mais completo lá.